# What does "Target has edges with more than two polygons" mean?

Tags: topology, surface-deform

I was trying to use a surface deform modifier on a model and when I tried it, it says "Target has edges with more than two polygons", and I don't know what this means

[image]

Comment: It means your mesh is not manifold (watertight)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Answer (score 12):

That's mean that you have a structure like this in your model (used in target field - "head" in your case)

3 faces has one common edge:

[image]

If you're sure that your surface is solid, try to remove doubles by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> (select all), <kbd>M</kbd> → **By Distance**

To find these edges, run **Select** ⇾ **Select All by Trait** ⇾ **Non-manifold** then press <kbd>F9</kbd> and uncheck everything except **"Multiple Faces"**

[image]

It will select all edges that's not pass that rule.